# Change max open file limit and broke ubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, 18.04, ulimit

Following a tutorial I added the line

```
fs.file-max = 4096
```

to `/etc/sysctl.conf` and ran `sudo sysctl -p` to update the max number of open files.

Now if I try to do anything I just get an error saying 'Too many open files'. I can't open any program or even enter a terminal to undo my changes.

I can enter into recovery mode, but then I cannot edit the `sysctl.conf` file (it gives the error message  `Error writing /etc/sysctl.conf: Read-only file system` when trying to save). Is there anyway to undo this horror?

I'm on Xubuntu 18.04

Comment: How do you mean that in recovery mode you cannot edit `sysctl.conf`?

Comment: "I can enter into recovery mode, but then I cannot edit the sysctl.conf file" Why not? And I would use a live session boot.

Comment: In recover mode, if I `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf` and try to save, I get the message `Error writing /etc/sysctl.conf: Read-only file system`

Comment: So remount it with rw and not r ;)